# Mysql keeps losing permissions on 21.04

Tags: permissions, mysql, 21.04

I have this problem where mysql community server keeps getting error code 13 (permission denied) at random, using `sudo chown -R mysql.mysql /etc/mysql` and `sudo chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql` will fix the problem temporarily, but then the next day ubuntu will completely forget the permissions and the server will crash again.
I'm at the end of my rope here and I cant seem to find anything that can permanantly fix it, trying to use mmh to debug will cause the bug to happen again so I cant use it to show grants because it simply refuses to install.

Comment: Does the `mysqld` process run under its own user `mysql`?

Comment: Yes it does, i made sure of that when it was installed

Comment: It is unlikely that Ubuntu is “forgetting” the ownership of just the MySQL directories, as this would be a massive problem for millions of people and companies around the world. If the file permissions are changing, one of three things is happening: a scheduled job is blindly changing ownership, a human is blindly changing ownership, a storage device is failing. You will need to do some leg work to figure out exactly which of those three causes is the culprit 

Comment: Well, I must have had a really bad fluke to lead up to this because now i cant connect at all even when the server is running, seems the permission problem was a precursor to a much worse problem, firewall isnt the problem, neither is permissions